# Issue using Distinct within a list of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

when I'm trying to remove duplicates from a list of custom objects,

the following are my failed attempt:

1-

```
model.DatesList = model.DatesList .Distinct().ToList();
```

2 -

```
List<DateTimeMask> newDates = new List<DateTimeMask>();
foreach (DateTimeMask _date in DatesList)
{
   if (!newDates.Contains(_date)) newDates.Add(_date);
}
DatesList = newDates;
```

3 -

```
model.DatesList = model.DatesList.Select(x=> new DateTimeMask
                                  {
                                    DayOfTheWeek = x.DayOfTheWeek,
                                    DateToString = x.DateToString,
                                    DateTallinn = x.DateTallinn,
                                  }).Distinct().ToList();
```

What am I doing wrong?

thanks for the help

edit: this is how the object look like

```
public class DateTimeMask
{
   public string DayOfTheWeek { get; set; }
   public string DateToString { get; set; }
   public DateTime DateTallinn { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What does `DateTimeMask` look like? Does it implement equality?

Comment: it's just something to help me to show stuff easily with @diplayfor [updated]

Comment: Could you perhaps show a small subset of the data that you expect to work, but doesn't? E.g. Do the dates contain times?

Comment: Since it's a class, the default check for equality is referential equality, so distinct will only remove objects that are the same reference, not ones with the same values.

Comment: I think that's it, thanks @JonathonChase